# How to use @Valid annotation in Spring-Data-Rest?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-data-rest

I am confused how to use @Valid annotation for Spring data rest.

I have entity class 'User'

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @ToString @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor  // from lombok
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 50)
    private String email;

    @Size(min = 8, max = 20)
    private String password;
}
```

And 'UserRepository'

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

As I have used @Size annotation in entity(User).

But how to apply validation on api data i.e. how to use @Valid (to validate request body) as rest api ends are created by 'spring-data-rest'.

Comment: How does your controller look like?

Comment: I am using spring-data-rest, so we don't need to create controller. Basic api ends like '/users' [POST], '/users' [GET] are created by spring itself. So how can we validate request body.

Comment: Please share your controller code

Comment: @Shiva Gupta I dont have experience in spring data rest but This might help
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators .Check out the code from its github repo.

Comment: @Eklavya Thanks it worked.